# Forward message using SendMessageAsync

Tags: forward, telegram-api, wtelegramclient

I'm not able to use the SendMessageAsync method to forward a message.

Is there any way to do it?

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use the `SendMessageAsync` helper method for that. You need to use the API method `Messages_ForwardMessages`

Here is an example code that forwards the pinned message from **from_chat**  to **to_chat**:

```cs
using var client = new WTelegram.Client(Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable);
await client.LoginUserIfNeeded();
var chats = await client.Messages_GetAllChats();

var from_chat = chats.chats[1234567890];  // source chat
var to_chat = chats.chats[1234567891];    // destination chat
var fullChat = await client.GetFullChat(from_chat);
var msgId = fullChat.full_chat.PinnedMsg; // id of msg in source chat

await client.Messages_ForwardMessages(from_chat, new[] { msgId }, new[] { WTelegram.Helpers.RandomLong() }, to_chat);
```